# Calculate probability distribution of events overlapping

Tags: probability

I'm making changes to a software server, and I'm trying to get an idea of how many people are connected to it at any given time.

I know the number of connections that are initiated during each hour (i.e. the average number of connections that are initiated between 5:00 and 6:00 each day):

- During the busiest hour, 416 connections are initiated
- On average across all hours of the day, 187 connections are initiated in each one-hour period

I also know that each connection remains open for 168 seconds.

Finally, there's nothing that causes certain specific times to be preferred (i.e. there's no reason that more connections will be initiated on the hour, as opposed to on the 17th minute of the hour).

I would like to get a rough idea of how many people will be connected, on average, at the same time. I would also like an idea of the maximum number of connections that I can usually expect to see (i.e. 99% of the time there will not be more than X connections).

So, if I take the busiest hour of the day (when there are 416 connections), and I know that each connection lasts 168 seconds, how do I get a probability distribution for the maximum number of connections that will overlap during that hour?